# Hibernate error when inserting data between related entities with Composite Keys

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to insert the data into an entity on the @ManyToOne relationship end. Both tables share a composite primary key (althought the database does not have any constraints at all). I have modelled my related entities as following:

Entity one:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP_GOALS_PHASES")
public class EmployeeGoalsAssessmentPhasesJPA implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "APP_ID", referencedColumnName = "APP_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMP_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "CYCLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "CYCLE_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "GOAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "GOAL_ID")
    })
    private EmployeeGoalsAssessmentJPA goalId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PHASE_ID")
    private Long phaseId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "APP_ID")
    private Long appId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private Long empId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CYCLE_ID")
    private Long cycleId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GOAL_ID")
    private Long goalIdentifier;

    @Column(name = "GOAL_RATE")
    private Double goalRate;

    @Column(name = "GOAL_WEIGHTED")
    private Double goalWeightedRate;

    @Column(name = "GOAL_COMMENT")
    private String goalComment;

    @Embedded()
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "empId", column = @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "creationDate", column = @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "updatedByEmpId", column = @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "lastUpdatedOn", column = @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")),
    })
    private ChangeHistory historyOfChanges;
```

Second entity:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP_GOALS")
public class EmployeeGoalsAssessmentJPA implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @Column(name="APP_ID")
    private Long appId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private Long empId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CYCLE_ID")
    private Long periodId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "goals2019_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="goals2019_generator", sequenceName = "GOALS2019_SEQ", allocationSize=25)
    @Column(name="GOAL_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long goalId;

    @Column(name = "GOAL_NAME")
    private String goalName;

    @Column(name="GOAL_DESC")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="GOAL_POSITION")
    private Long goalPosition;

    @Column(name="GOAL_MEASURE")
    private String goalMeasure;

    @Column(name="GOAL_WEIGHT")
    private Double goalWeight;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MID_REV_STATUS_ID")
    private MidReviewStatusJPA midReviewStatus;

    @Column(name="MID_REV_COMMENT")
    private String midReviewComment;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "goalId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<EmployeeGoalsAssessmentPhasesJPA> goalsAssessmentPhases = new HashSet<>();

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "empId", column = @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "creationDate", column = @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "updatedByEmpId", column = @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "lastUpdatedOn", column = @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")),
    })
    private ChangeHistory historyOfChanges;
```

Now I want to saveOrUpdate data in the EmployeeGoalsAssessmentPhasesJPA, which is obviously connected with EmployeeGoalsAssessmentJPA. Problem is, whenever, I try to do so, I get the error during saving, saying that SqlExceptionHelper:142 - The index 13 is out of range. I have switched into debug mode of hibernate and managed to figure out that this what is going under the hood:

```
select
        employeego_.PHASE_ID,
        employeego_.GOAL_ID,
        employeego_.EMP_ID,
        employeego_.CYCLE_ID,
        employeego_.APP_ID,
        employeego_.GOAL_COMMENT as GOAL_COM6_11_,
        employeego_.CYCLE_ID as CYCLE_ID4_11_,
        employeego_.GOAL_ID as GOAL_ID2_11_,
        employeego_.EMP_ID as EMP_ID3_11_,
        employeego_.APP_ID as APP_ID5_11_,
        employeego_.GOAL_RATE as GOAL_RAT7_11_,
        employeego_.GOAL_WEIGHTED as GOAL_WEI8_11_,
        employeego_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION9_11_,
        employeego_.CREATED_BY as CREATED10_11_,
        employeego_.LAST_UPDATED_DATE as LAST_UP11_11_,
        employeego_.LAST_UPDATED_BY as LAST_UP12_11_ 
    from
        EMP_GOALS_PHASES employeego_ 
    where
        employeego_.PHASE_ID=? 
        and employeego_.GOAL_ID=? 
        and employeego_.EMP_ID=? 
        and employeego_.CYCLE_ID=? 
        and employeego_.APP_ID=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        employeego_.PHASE_ID,
        employeego_.GOAL_ID,
        employeego_.EMP_ID,
        employeego_.CYCLE_ID,
        employeego_.APP_ID,
        employeego_.GOAL_COMMENT as GOAL_COM6_11_,
        employeego_.CYCLE_ID as CYCLE_ID4_11_,
        employeego_.GOAL_ID as GOAL_ID2_11_,
        employeego_.EMP_ID as EMP_ID3_11_,
        employeego_.APP_ID as APP_ID5_11_,
        employeego_.GOAL_RATE as GOAL_RAT7_11_,
        employeego_.GOAL_WEIGHTED as GOAL_WEI8_11_,
        employeego_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION9_11_,
        employeego_.CREATED_BY as CREATED10_11_,
        employeego_.LAST_UPDATED_DATE as LAST_UP11_11_,
        employeego_.LAST_UPDATED_BY as LAST_UP12_11_ 
    from
        EMP_GOALS_PHASES employeego_ 
    where
        employeego_.PHASE_ID=? 
        and employeego_.GOAL_ID=? 
        and employeego_.EMP_ID=? 
        and employeego_.CYCLE_ID=? 
        and employeego_.APP_ID=?
2019-12-16 19:44:26,720 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [30]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,720 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1900]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,720 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [57]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,720 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [201912]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,720 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [1]

insert 
    into
        EMP_GOALS_PHASES
        (GOAL_COMMENT, CYCLE_ID, GOAL_ID, EMP_ID, APP_ID, GOAL_RATE, GOAL_WEIGHTED, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, PHASE_ID) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        EMP_GOALS_PHASES
        (GOAL_COMMENT, CYCLE_ID, GOAL_ID, EMP_ID, APP_ID, GOAL_RATE, GOAL_WEIGHTED, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, PHASE_ID) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [TEST IF CHILD ENTITY ONLY GETS UPDATED IF PARENT IS UPDATED]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [201912]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [3750]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - [57]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [6] as [DOUBLE] - [8.0]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [7] as [DOUBLE] - [26.6]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [8] as [DATE] - [2019-12-16]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,779 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [9] as [BIGINT] - [57]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,780 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [10] as [DATE] - [2019-12-16]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,780 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [11] as [BIGINT] - [57]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,780 TRACE  BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [12] as [BIGINT] - [30]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,780 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [13] as [BIGINT] - [1900]
2019-12-16 19:44:26,781 INFO   AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2019-12-16 19:44:26,781 WARN   SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
2019-12-16 19:44:26,781 ERROR  SqlExceptionHelper:142 - The index 13 is out of range.
```

Now, obviously this index 13 is not something I have in my table, so why does Hibernate try to use that to insert data? I am confused as to how does Hibernate operate. I think that my model is also messy because of the improper handling of the composite keys, however I would like to understand what is going on there.

The business goal is simple: to be able to save many phases for one goal and update it whenever it is updated. I have omitted getters, setters and equals and hashCode for brevity. My database is SQL Server.

Comment: the insert statement accepts 12 parameters (12 questionmarks ?, positional) but there are 13 parameters".   binding parameter [13] as [BIGINT] - [1900] <-- there is no position for this parameter.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.. My only wonder is, how, when and where does hibernate include this parameter. I am trying to save the whole object that I prepare beforehand using lombok builder, so it contains only field of the class

Comment: I managed to figure out that the 13th parameter comes from the parent entity of the relationship and it is the GOAL_ID, which is annotated as an @Id of this entity (one of 4), but I don't know why does hibernate want that as yet another field for that entity as I have already defined it in the relationship